# Cancel event listeners from element

Tags: dart, angular-dart

Is there a way to cancel/remove all event listeners from an element? I didn't set these listeners by myself so I don't have a `StreamSubscription` I could use. I need to get them somehow.

So some library did this:

```
querySelector('body').onMouseUp.listen(handler);
```

And I want to remove that (and all other) handlers again.

Comment: I doubt this is possible. Perhaps you can add an `onMouseUp` event handler in a child element and call `stopPropagation` and/or `stopImmediatePropagation` on the event. I never used that and don't know exactly how it works but might be worth a try.

Comment: I've already tried preventDefault(), which didn't help. I'll try stop*Propagation(). Looks like this is a problem in Javascript too. Chrome Dev tools have a getEventListeners() function but it is not available in user context.

Comment: stopPropagation() on a child element works. Not perfect but OK. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an `onMouseUp` event handler in a child element and call `stopPropagation` and/or `stopImmediatePropagation` on the event to prevent the event from propagating up.